Errores BrowserStack IPA React Native
Estoy probando el funcionamiento de un IPA desarrollado con React Native con el fin de probar su funcionamiento en distintos iPhones, y la aplicación funciona aparentemente bien. Incluso en dos iphones físicos que utilicé, la app funciona fluidamente sin ningún tipo de comportamiento extraño. Pero algo que me llama la atención es que cuando testeo el funcionamiento de la app en BrowserStack en los distintos iPhones aparecen logs de error cuando estoy corriendo la app:

Esos errores no crashean la app ni nada por el estilo cuando estoy probando.
Esos errores o warnings son algo "normal" cuando corremos la app en BrowserStack o no? He googleado muchos de los logs que aparecen y no he encontrado una respuesta clara del porque se generan.
